# How can I align photos for stop motion?

Tags: software, stop-motion

I just began to take the same photo everyday, in order to try to make a stop motion over the fall/winter season.
As I have took now 3 photo (that's a start) I realized that they will not be well aligned.

So I'm looking if a software will do this for me. I'm thinking of something where you click 3 or 4 precise point in each photo, and then the software crop/align/resize the picture so they all fit nicely together.

I'm pretty sure this kind of things must exist.

Answer (score 2):

To ease in the alignment of the photos, you could use something like [Anazi Stop Motion Animator](http://www.animateclay.com/index.php/articles/72-free-downloads/129-anasazi-stop-motion-animator).

It has an "Onion Skin" feature that allows you to see two different frames at the same time to help in aligning them.

You may find some good advice on how to use this software or what software others are using for this by searching for some stop animation sites.  The only site I have personally seen is [brickfilms.com](http://brickfilms.com/resources/) which is a stop motion animation site specializing in animating LEGOs.  On their resources page you might find some helpful advice.